# jQuery trigger 2nd button when first is clicked

Tags: jquery

I am trying to trigger a second button click when the first one is clicked using jQuery, I have this..

```js
jQuery( "#dup_button" ).click(function() {
    alert("Duplicate Button Pressed");
    jQuery("input[name='add-to-cart']").click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="dup_button">
  Click Me
</button>

<button name="add-to-cart" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">Add To Cart</button>
```

Is this ok for a selector?  Can I select the button by name like this?

Comment: Should be `button[name='add-to-cart']` instead of `input[name='add-to-cart']`.

Comment: Remember, calling `.click()` will execute that elements bound handler from the code, it *will not* do native functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to *fire* a click event on the button, maybe use [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/), not click `.click()`

`.click()` registers what happens when the element is *clicked* (its click handler) but does not emit the click event.

You might also want to try "functionalizing" your code like:

```
function thing1() {
  // things happen
  alert("Duplicate Button Pressed");
}

function thing2() {
  // other things happen
}

jQuery("#dup_button").click(function() {
  thing1();
});

jQuery("input[name='add-to-cart']").click(function() {
  // any"thing" can happen! lol.
  thing1();
  thing2();
});
```

The above code allows for a little more flexibility. You can call `thing1()` or `thing2()` independently of each other or "at the same time".

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery( "#dup_button" ).click(function() {
    //alert("Duplicate Button Pressed");
    jQuery("button[name='add-to-cart']").click();
});

$("button[name='add-to-cart']").click(function() {
  alert( "Cart button clicked." );
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g5h9exp6/

Answer (score 1):

jQuery("button[name='add-to-cart']").trigger( "click" );